# Software update on iPod touch 4th generation

Tags: software-update, ipod-touch

I have an iPod touch 4th generation that won't download software update or reset to factory settings.

What can I do?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) What is the current version of iOS running on your iPod touch? iOS 6.1.6 is the last release available for iPod touch 4th gen. What error message do you see when trying to reset to factory settings? Please [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/347610/edit) your post to share the information.

Answer (score 1):

The last iOS release available for iPod touch 4th generation is iOS 6.1.6. If you have a Mac or PC handy, you can install iTunes and restore the iOS firmware using it.

To download iOS 6.1.6 firmware for your iPod touch 4th generation, visit [IPSW.me](https://ipsw.me/), select your device and click download. Make sure the firmware you select is signed. (Alternatively, you can use [this](https://ipsw.me/api/ios/v4/ota/download/iPod4,1/10B500?prerequisite=10A523) link to download directly).

The firmware is downloaded from Apple's server and safe to use. They are digitally signed and are verified by Apple while installing.